# How do I turn off css + js optimization in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I have this problem -> http://www.joomlart.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-56070.html?s=ea76d427b6f743bf2517d22569d1c8f5 (you don't really have to read)

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in .... file

.. and it was there solved "by turning css + js optimization off". How do I do that in joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla doesn't have css, js optimization by deafult. If question is about Joomla Art's templates based on T3-framework then it's in template's global settings (extensions -> template manager -> your template -> global -> css & javascript compress)